# PHP equivalent of JavaScript's parseInt function?

Tags: php, function, digit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if a variable is a natural number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563367/check-if-a-variable-is-a-natural-number)

Just came across where I need to sanitize an input and remove all non-digit characters with PHP. Thought of making a function myself, but just first wanted to check up on the possible built-in functions, so I won't have to spend extra time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: check [php.net/Type Casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: Why not just use intval?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use regular expression as below

```
$int = (int) preg_replace('/\D/', '', $strNonNumeric);
```

OR

```
$int = (int) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $strNonNumeric);
```

Comment: ah, exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @think123 - it's worth pointing out that (a) this does not produce an int; it's still a string, albeit only containing digits, and (b) regex is overkill for this scenario.

Comment: True, but this is one of the ones that actually works. I'll edit it all the same.

Comment: WARNING! This is very dangerous beacuse numbers in the same string  will be read as one. (es. asd25asd56aa -> 2556)

Answer (score 35):

There isn't a direct equivalent to `pareseInt()` in PHP because PHP doesn't have a `NaN` data type. `parseInt()` will produce `NaN` if the value can't be parsed.

In addition, `parseInt()` has the radix parameter, which none of the PHP options give you.

But that said, if all you want to do is turn a string into an integer, then there are several options:

```
$int = (int)$string;

$int = intval($string);

$int = settype($string,'integer');
```

Those three will all work in much the same way. There may be some edge cases where `intval()` differs from the other two, but in general, they will turn a string into an int. In the absence of `NaN`, they all output `0` (zero) if the string is non numeric and can't be parsed. But this should be sufficient for most DB sanitation purposes.

If you really want a the `NaN` on error, the closest you'll get is `null`. You can get this using `filter_var()`:

```
$value = filter_var(FALSE, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
```

If you just want to check that the string is numeric, the `is_numeric()` function can do that:

```
$bool = is_numeric($string);
```

However, it returns true for decimals and also for scientific notation, so may not be perfect for most situations. A better option is `ctype_digit()` which returns true if the string is made up only of digits:

```
$bool = ctype_digit($string);
```

If non e of this suits, there is always the regex option, using `preg_match()` or `preg_replace()`, but these are definitely overkill for this kind of scenario.

Comment: Using (int) and intval() are very error-proof, but be aware that if the string represents a floating point number (i.e. has decimals), then these functions simply remove whatever comes after the point. So "3.999" becomes 3.

Comment: @Wytze: true, but the question was asking specifically to remove non-digit characters, so the assumption would be that it isn't a decimal. There are other options if you need to handle decimals.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
$string = "90"; //string
$myInt = (int) $string; //parse to int
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not exactly what I want. `(int)` won't remove all non-digit characters, it will just return `0` if there are any non-digit characters inside the string.

Comment: @think123: Type casting `(int)` will do the same as `parseInt()` in javascript. This is what you asked, isn't it?

Comment: Straight to the point.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using FILTER_VALIDATE_INT Filter.

[about Filters on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Comment: -1 Please don't put a w3schools link. Put a `php.net` one instead, and I'll give you your vote back.

Comment: +2 gave you your vote back, as guaranteed.

Comment: Oh and just for some reasoning why: http://www.w3fools.com

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sscanf (just like you do in C)

```
<?php

    $str = "10";

    sscanf($str, "%d", $intVal);
    $intVal *= 10;

    echo $intVal;
?>
```

**Output:**

100